# How to code current date - to select rows where actual_date is = or > than the current_date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following SQL for SQL Server 2014 (v12.00.6433), `e.actual_date` is a `datetime Null` column. The code shown results in an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CURRENT_DATE'.

The purpose here is that we want to see all clients activity only for the past 2 and half years from the current date.

```
select distinct 
    ac.people_id, ac.first_name, ac.last_name, ac.id_no, 
    ad.city, ed.is_service_event, co.description as County,
    pe.program_name, pe.program_start_date, pe.program_end_date, 
    el.actual_date, el.approved_date, el.program_providing_service, 
    el.duration, ed.event_name
from
    all_clients_view ac
inner join 
    address ad on ad.people_id = ac.people_id
left join 
    county co on ad.county = co.county_id
inner join 
    program_enrollment_expanded_view pe on pe.people_id = ac.people_id
inner join 
    event_log el on ac.people_id = el.people_id
inner join 
    event_definition ed on el.event_definition_id = ed.event_definition_id
where 
    el.actual_date > CURRENT_DATE() - (365 * 2 + 366 / 2)
```

Comment: Perhaps you intended to use [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timestamp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Answer (score 0):

`CURRENT_DATE()` is not a sql server function. Try replacing it with `GETDATE()`.

Going two and a half years back can also be done by substracting 30 months like this:
`DATEADD(month, -30, GETDATE())`

Comment: Or better yet: use `SYSDATETIME()` which returns more precise information that `GETDATE()` ....

Comment: I tried now and TIMESTAMP seems to work fine. Is there any problem using TIMESTAMP or is it better to use Getdate? or SYSDATETIME().

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and GETDATE can both be used, no problem using either. Both return the date with a millisecond precision (rounded to .000, .003, .007 increments). SYSDATETIME is rounded to 100 nanoseconds. Both are more than enough precision for your use case.